# HTML Submit Button Explained

Tags: php, html, submit

I'm just trying to understand the submit button within php.

I know that it performs that action stated within the form tag. So basically what I have is an form tag that only defines it's ID, i.e. no method attribute nor action. And within this form is a submit button. This input element only defines the type as submit, i.e. no name attribute nor id nor value.

Quickly describing the file: It has two input text elements which are required and a submit button. When i view this file in chrome, and i've clicked the submit button, a pop up shows below the required fields which i have not entered text in stating "required field".

I love this function however, it doesn't check for spaces, i.e. " ".

So back to my question, could someone possibly tell me what the submit button actually does or possibly what methods does it call when i click on it even though the form it is in has no action defined.

Comment: You just told us you have a button, in detail, then asked us what the button does. can you not just click it?

Comment: It is a little more work, but you can expand upon the required attribute by implementing your own javascript validation in the submit button's `onclick` function.

Comment: yoh this is a retarded question... gonna give it a shot and delete this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the button is clicked, the browser detects this and submits the form back to the server. This has nothing to do with PHP, it's simply the browser implementing what the HTML specification stipulates.

Since your form does not have an `action` attribute, what happens is that the browser gathers the values of all eligible input controls in the form, turns that into a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and makes an HTTP [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request to the current URL using that query string. The HTML5 spec [covers this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html) in detail.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I just realized now that it is indeed html related and not php. Apologies. And thanks for the suggestion. It does actually clarify alot for me.

Answer (score 1):

The submit button offers one possible interface for the submission of the form. It's like the send button for a text message. While there are alternatives to submit the form, the submit button is the HTML option.

Comment: silly me! i don't know why i assumed it was a php button. there's no such thing. lol, gui for php... (wait i could be wrong).

thanks andy!

Answer (score 1):

When a form's `action` is empty, the form submits the GET data to the page that form is on. (Basically, it reloads itself, with the new form data attached.) So you could write your PHP code at the top of the same page to manipulate the data.

In your PHP code at the top of the page, you can test whether or not your form sent data in those two required fields. If one or both are empty, you can `echo` a message to the user telling them the fields are required.

Comment: thanks nick. i'm still pretty new to web forms. i'm a java guy so this stuff is kinda foreign but thanks to peeps like you, i'm getting there!